# Normalization in the one-loop vacuum amplitude (partiton function) of the bosonic string

Tags: string-theory, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator, normalization

This question stems from the string theory book by [Ibanez and Uranga](https://books.google.com/books?id=vAUUu6DpVkUC&lpg=PA625&dq=ibanez%20uranga&pg=PA83#v=onepage&q&f=true) [page 83, [link to excerpt]](https://books.google.com/books?id=vAUUu6DpVkUC&lpg=PA625&dq=ibanez%20uranga&pg=PA83#v=onepage&q&f=true), and Polchinksi [page 209 of volume 1].

The partition function has a piece $Z_{i,n}$ which Ibanez and Uranga evaluate as

$$Z_{i,n}(\tau) = \sum_{K=0}^{\infty} \langle 0|(\alpha_{n}^{i})^K q^{N_{i,n}}(\alpha^{i}_{-n})^K|0\rangle = \sum_{K=0}^{\infty}q^{Kn} = (1-q^n)^{-1}$$

where $N_{i,n} = \alpha^{i}_{-n}\alpha^{i}_{n}$.

I am a bit confused by the normalization here. **What is wrong with the following?**

Define (for $n > 0$),

$$a_{n}^{i} = \frac{\alpha_{n}^{i}}{\sqrt{n}}, \qquad {a_{n}^{i}}^\dagger = \frac{\alpha_{-n}^{i}}{\sqrt{n}}$$

so that $[a_n^i, a_{-n}^j] = \delta^{ij}$. Then, states for the closed string are labeled by $|N,\tilde{N};l\rangle$ (in the lightcone gauge, following conventions of Polchinski vol. 1) and one has

$$|N,\tilde{N};l\rangle = \left[\prod_{i=2}^{D-1}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\alpha^i_{-n})^{N_{in}}(\tilde{\alpha}^i_{-n})^{\tilde{N}_{in}}}{\sqrt{n^{N_{in}}N_{in}!n^{\tilde{N}_{in}}\tilde{N}_{in}!}}\right]|0,0;l\rangle$$

which can be rewritten in terms of the $a, a^\dagger$ as

$$|N,\tilde{N};l\rangle = \left[\prod_{i=2}^{D-1}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{({a_n^i}^\dagger)^{N_{in}}({\tilde{a}_n^i}^\dagger)^{\tilde{N}_{in}}}{\sqrt{N_{in}!\tilde{N}_{in}!}}\right]|0,0;l\rangle$$

So from all this it is clear that the "standard" bosonic harmonic oscillator algebra is generated by the $a, a^\dagger$ operators. In terms of $a, a^\dagger$ operators then, in the expression for $Z_{i,n}(\tau)$, I'd have expected factors of $n^k k!$ in the summand.

**Is $(\alpha^i_{-n})^K|0\rangle = |N = k\rangle$ or is $({a^i_{n}}^\dagger)^K|0\rangle = \sqrt{k!}|N = k\rangle$**?

I know that the result is correct, so there's just some confusion about the normalization.

*I'm also fairly certain that the doubt I have is very trivial, and I've overlooked something but after spending a fair amount of time on this, I couldn't find the mistake.*